# Defining interfaces without exporting them

Tags: typescript

If I have a file myinterface.ts

```
interface MyInterface {
    foo() : string
}
```

and a second file myimplementation.ts

```
class MyImplementation implements MyInterface {
    ...
}
```

***Question 1:*** Why does this work? I'm not exporting the interface.

Then, if I want to change `foo() : string` to `foo() : SomeType` where `SomeType` is defined in another module, I need to modify myinterface.ts to be:

```
import { SomeType } form 'some-module';
interface MyInterface {
    foo() : SomeType
}
```

This causes errors in myimplementation.ts saying "cannot find name 'MyInterface'".

***Question 2:*** What changes about the way a *.ts file is changed when you add an *import* (or an *export*) versus when the file just contains interfaces (and they aren't even marked as export).

I understand that the best practice would be to simply mark my interface as export and to do `import {MyInterface} from 'myinterface';`, but I'm trying to understand why the original version works, and what the implications are.

Comment: TS interfaces aren't real in the sense that they produce executable code, they act as contracts for the type system and are discarded before output. They are much like `enum`s in that sense. You can't import or export them because they don't exist.

Comment: I understand that, however it does seem to be valid to do `import { SomeInterface } from 'some-module';`, so I imagine it's some sort of hint to TSC. I'm actually curious about using interfaces defined in a different file.

Comment: @ssube that's not entirely true. If I change the interface implemented to `SomeUndefinedInterface` then a compiler error is thrown. The interface must be defined somewhere, and I agree with @Kir that it's mystifying that it knows about the definition in the other file without an explicit import: "Conversely, to consume a variable, function, class, interface, etc. exported from a different module, it has to be imported using one of the import forms. Modules are declarative; the relationships between modules are specified in terms of imports and exports at the file level." Typescript handbook

Comment: @Orphid "must be defined somewhere" !== executable code. Interfaces are discarded during compilation, after type checking occurs, but before modules are output and exports set up.

Comment: @ssube that is true, but we are talking about compilation here. These are compiler errors. Interestingly, if i change the code to explicitly export the interface, then it wont compile. Seems to be that if no exports are defined, everything is exported as a global.

Comment: @Orphid - that's what I observe as well, but it doesn't seem to be defined in any documentation that I can find. Perhaps this should be raised with the TS team themselves.

Comment: @Kir - I suspect it's actually to do with the commonjs module system. You may see different behaviour if you use a different module system. Take a look at the link at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: @Orphid - have you found a module system where this behavior is not exhibited? AMD seems to behave the same way for me, for example. I think the type resolution happens during the parser step, and not as it's trying to output modules.

Answer (score 1):

Quick investigation:

I have this in InterfaceFile.ts:

```
interface MyInterface {
    foo(): string
}

var s = 4;
```

And this in a file called ImplFile.ts

```
class MyImplementation implements MyInterface {
    foo(): string {
        return 'foo';
    }
}

s.toExponential(1);
```

Now, when I look at the compiled InterfaceFile.js I see this:

```
var s = 4;
```

And the `s.toExponential(1)` in ImplFile.ts cause the compiler no problems (Webstorm styles it as a global too).

Now, if I explicitly export `s`;

```
interface MyInterface {
    foo(): string
}

export var s = 4;
```

I get this:

```
exports.s = 4;
```

And **neither** `s` nor `MyInterface` are available without an import

So, it seems like if you don't export anything in the file, it's treated as a global. I suspect that if export anything, the file becomes a module.

Comment: The link above simply explains that `exports` is a reference to `module exports`, so doing `exports = XXX` will not work.